Schema Incompatibility Issue
we are pushing an event into a topic , but getting an error `Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject "x.proto"  this schema has a reference of other schema also .
details:
[{errorType:"ONEOF_FIELD_REMOVED", description:"The old schema is missing a oneof field at path '#/y/schema/2' in the new schema"

does the updated schema get registered itself when producer trying to publish an event into a topic , or it first pass the compatibility check , then only get registered
I tried to delete the old subjects , it worked . but we can't do it because if we do so then we have to do this across all different clusters .
